# Collapsing Navigation Bar, Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I coded my HTML index to have the navigation bar replaced by a button when the screen gets narrower. But, when the button is clicked, the navigation bar elements are not displayed as I expected. hope somebody can help me.

If I copy-paste the same nav-bar code into w3schools bootstrap simulator (http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h) the elements do show up when I click the button (with narrow screen)

here is the piece of code I'm talking about:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="file:///C:/Users/Maria/Desktop/Vale%26Andrea/indexVA.html" class="navbar-left"><img src="images/cuori.png" height="42" alt="Valentina e Andrea" title="Valentina e Andrea">Valentina e Andrea</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="noi.html" target="_blank">Noi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Il Grande Giorno</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lista Nozze</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1C2kx4ete4K7238-VPHktfyCymZJqh-FjWh2fstvgy3g/viewform" target="_blank">Scrivici!</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>


<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Auguri a <a href="noi.html" target="_blank" role="button"> NOI! </a></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how exactly do you want it to display and how is it displayed right now? Pasting your code into a codepen and importing jquery and bootstrap creates a standard bootstrap menu so I don't get what you want to accomplish http://codepen.io/emiemi/pen/BKyOGJ

Comment: Do you have any custom CSS that might be hiding or chaning colors of your menu elements? Everything looks fine to me, but I noticed that you have not included any CSS in your question or link.

Comment: Whenever I make the screen narrower than 767px, the navigation links on the left side of the bar are replaced by a list icon (the button I classified as 'navbar-toggle' in my piece of code) and that works fine. The problem is that when I click on the button, the 4 links list do not show up (while it does from the simulator link I sent in my question). I've also checked whether the problem could be my custom.css, but I get the same issue even deleting that from the folder.